# assign enum value to another view controller

Tags: swift, enums

Hey guys I'm facing some troubles while trying to sent some information from a function inside a UICollectionViewCell

on my first viewController which is call OffersUSViewController I have

```
private enum BpAmocoOfferItem {
    case carousel(items: [CarouselOfferItems])
    case spendChallenge
    case fnboPromotion
    case referAFriend
    case priceMatch
    case communitySupport
}
    
enum CarouselOfferItems {
    case fnboPromotion
    case referAFriend
    case priceMatch
    case communitySupport
}

var carouselItems: [CarouselOfferItems] = []
```

on the cellForRowAt I have a function for the case **carousel** which leads to the next viewController setup
but whenever I try to call the

```
cell.configure(withNumberOfItems: items.count, arrayValues: carouselItems)
```

always shows an error :

*Cannot convert value of type '[OffersUSViewController.CarouselOfferItems]' to expected argument type '[OffersCarouselTableViewCell.CarouselOfferItems]'*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    case .carousel(items: let items):
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OffersCarouselTableViewCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? OffersCarouselTableViewCell else { break }
        cell.configure(withNumberOfItems: items.count, arrayValues: carouselItems)
                
        tableCell = cell
    }
```

everytime I try to pass the information to the next viewcontroller for this **carouselItems**

always shows the error

on the second view controller called OffersCarouselTableViewCell

I have

```
public var collectionViewData : [Section] = []
public enum Section {
    case bpAmocoOffers(items: [CarouselOfferItems])
}
    
public enum CarouselOfferItems {
    case fnboPromotion
    case referAFriend
    case priceMatch
    case communitySupport
}
```

and the configure function

```
func configure(withNumberOfItems newNumberOfItems: Int, arrayValues: [CarouselOfferItems]) {
    numberOfItems = newNumberOfItems
    var data: [Section] = []
    let bpAmocoOffers : [CarouselOfferItems] = arrayValues
    if bpAmocoOffers.isEmpty == false {
        data.append(.bpAmocoOffers(items: bpAmocoOffers))
    }
    collectionViewData = data
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

which is this information that I need

```
CarouselOfferItems
```

what I'm trying to achieve if there's a smart option o do it is
pass the information from VC1 this specific part

```
var carouselItems: [CarouselOfferItems] = []
```

so I can order the assign the correct cell for the UICollectionViewCell

once I get that information I can append the items to the carousel sections

```
public enum Section {
    case bpAmocoOffers(items: [CarouselOfferItems])
}
    
public enum CarouselOfferItems {
    case fnboPromotion
    case referAFriend
    case priceMatch
    case communitySupport
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make `CarouselOfferItems` global, don’t put it inside view controller.